# Issue with two way binding in AngularJS Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, two-way-binding

I'm creating an AngularJS component

```
var notificationComponent = {
        templateUrl: "notification.html",
        controller: ['$rootScope', notificationController],
        bindings: {
            visible: "="
        }
    };
```

I want to use in HTML like below:

```
<notification visible="$rootScope.showNotification"></notification>
```

Basically I want to control '**visible**' property from any other component as true or false.

I tried achieving this by maintaining a variable in `$rootScope` named **showNotification**. But if I modify its value from any other component like:

```
$rootScope.showNotification = true;
```

Its not changing the '**visible**' property value.

As per my understanding following code does a two way binding in AngularJS component.

```
bindings: {
            visible: "="
        }
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: But keep in mind - using $root and $rootScope is not recommended way, this may cause unpredictable behavior, you should better plan your app architecture

Comment: @LuninRoman If i don't use $rootScope to track the flag showNotification what should be the better approach to achieve it.

Comment: You can design a service, for example `NotificationService` with methods `show` and `hide`, or at least using Angularjs $broadcast service to emit and watch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should `$root` in view to access `$rootScope`:

```
<notification visible="$root.showNotification"></notification>
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77zb8kvd/)**